# Need output in below format in oracle. I have tried with lag function it worked if we have only 2 rows in table

Tags: oracle

Consider below table table.

```
Id  balance
 1    100
 2    500
 3    4000
```

I need output in below format.

```
Id  balance begin_bal end_bal
1    100      0        100
2    500     100       600
3   4000     600      4600
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A little bit of analytics, as you presumed:

```
SQL> with test (id, balance) as
  2    (select 1,  100 from dual union all
  3     select 2,  500 from dual union all
  4     select 3, 4000 from dual
  5    ),
  6  temp as
  7    (select id, balance, sum(balance) over (order by id) rsum
  8     from test
  9    )
 10  select id,
 11    balance,
 12    nvl(lag(rsum) over (order by id), 0) begin_bal,
 13    rsum end_bal
 14  from temp
 15  order by id;

        ID    BALANCE  BEGIN_BAL    END_BAL
---------- ---------- ---------- ----------
         1        100          0        100
         2        500        100        600
         3       4000        600       4600

SQL>
```